# Getting the value from drop down list using PHP

Tags: php, sql

I have a form for users to enter values and update records.

The drop down menu looks like this:

```
    <select name="dateID" required>
        <option value="" disabled>Please select...</option>
        <option value="2">1920's</option>
        <option value="3">1930's</option>
        <option value="4">1940's</option>
        <option value="5">1950's</option>
        <option value="6">1960's</option>
        <option value="7">1970's</option>
        <option value="8">1980's</option>
        <option value="9">1990's</option>
    </select>
```

Then i get the value of the drop down chosen by using this:

```
$decade = $_GET['dateID'];
```

This is the part that is causing me problems i think.. my SQL statemen works when i try it in PHP MyAdmin but it doesn't work on the website.

Here is my SQL statement:

```
   $sql = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE details INNER JOIN date ON date.dateID = details.dateID SET details.year = '$year', details.description = '$description', details.dateID = '$decade' WHERE id='$recordID'") or die('Query error. try again: '.mysqli_error());
```

This is joining two tables, one which has the details in it and another which has decade and date ID according to that decade.

I am trying to assign the value of the drop down list to dateID which is in both the details and the date table, meaning that i can assign the decade to which ever value is assigned.

Why is the SQL not working?

If i replace the SQL with this it works:

```
"UPDATE details SET year = '$year', description = '$description' WHERE id='$recordID'"
```

Comment: This makes no sense. The drop down is not related to your query in your question the way that you have asked it.

Comment: you need double quotes ur query to get the value of variable

Comment: I have done this and it still doesn't work @Bsienn

Comment: @Bsienn is correct also i see you did like this :- `$decade = $_GET['dateID'];` but you no where use that variable `$decade` ?

Comment: "UPDATE details INNER JOIN date ON date.dateID = details.dateID SET details.year = '$year', details.description = '$description', details.dateID = '$dateID' WHERE id='$recordID'"   does not work either.

Comment: i see you did like this :- `$decade = $_GET['dateID'];` but you no where use that variable `$decade` ?

Comment: ahh this: details.dateID = '$dateID' shoud be changed to details.dateID = '$decade' but still not working

Comment: Explain what do u mean by "not working", do u get  any errors?

Comment: No errors, just isnt completing the SQL statement. When i enter the SQL into PHPmyAdmin it works @Bsienn

Comment: check what ur `$sql` variable returns. should be `true` on successful query. `var_dump($sql)` may help

Comment: besides that i dont see why ur query wont work

Comment: getting nothing back with that, this may be the way my pages are linked though

Comment: Note that your code is prone to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: i honestly dont understand why it isnt working! i cant see anything wrong with my code!

Comment: the url is receiving the new values but it isn't updating my database.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some recommendations:

1. Replace date with `date`. As date is also data type in MySql.
2. Relace `WHERE id='$recordID'` to `<table alias>.id`. As id may be present in both tables and you are using a JOIN.
3. Get values of the variables properly using proper escaping sequence e.g. instead of `"'$varname'"` use `"'".$varname."'"` or `"'{$varname}'"`

Hope this will help resolving the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback but none of those seem to work.  I don't understand why it isn't working @Imran

Comment: the url is receiving the new values but it isn't updating my database.

Comment: Please echo the ` $sql` variable. And then copy the query and run using phpMyAdmin in SQL tab. Or run it on MySql console.

Comment: After copying and running if you saw an error please mention it here.

Comment: @Gem yes why not raise your question in StackOverflow and someone will for sure answer or you can send me link and I can try answering that too.